# Fetch access-control-allow-origin

Tags: javascript, api, fetch

Estoy llamando a una API con fetch, al hacer el llamado me sale lo siguiente:

> Failed to load http://mppromocionales.com/ws_products.php: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost' is therefore not allowed access. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.

En la documentación me dieron dos datos:
Solicitud  API ***
Cuenta: ********

Tengo este script para el llamado de la api:

```js
const direccionUrl = 'http://mppromocionales.com/ws_products.php',
    parametros = {
      method: 'GET',
      mode: 'cors',
      redirect: 'follow',
      headers: new Headers({
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
      })
    },
    request = new Request(direccionUrl, parametros)
```

No logro acceder y no se donde podría agregar los datos que me dan para poder tener acceso.

Comment: Eso se hace desde el backend

Comment: Trata de hacer lo que dice el mensaje de error: "set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.". Cambia el mode a 'no-cors'.

Answer (score 3):

De lado del servidor, es decir, en tu **API** agrega las siguientes linea para permitir que se pueda accesar desde afuera del servidor:

```
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
//aquí agregamos solo los metodos que necesitemos
header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, PUT, DELETE');
```

Saludos, espero te funcione.